# Can someone give a concrete example of a unit test adding value when integration tests already exist?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

Let's assume we are not doing TDD (for which unit tests are obviously part and parcel), and have integration tests for all the use cases.

The integration tests assume assume a certain input and validate the output is as expected.

My thinking is that adding a unit test for a method that is traversed in an integration test, **using the same data as would exist in the method in the integration test**, would not expose any additional bugs.

That would lead to the conclusion that provided you have suffcient integration tests you do not then need to unit test the same code.

So, can someone give a concrete example where a unit test could expose a bug in the above scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Integration tests** can be seen as a form of [Acceptance Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceptance_testing). They ensure that the software is doing what it is *supposed* to be doing.

**Unit tests**, on the other hand, aren't particularly useful for customers. A customer is not concerned that the `InitializeServerConnection` is failing, but they *are* concerned that they're unable to send internal messages to their co-workers as a result.

So what good are unit tests for? They are a development tool, full stop. A unit test verifies that a cog in the machine is working properly. And if it is not, *it is very easy to see it failing*.

[Arialdo Martini offers a great explanation:](http://arialdomartini.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/unit-tests-lie-thats-why-i-love-them/)

> Oversimplifying, a software system can be seen as a network of cooperating modules. Since they cooperate, some of them depend on other.
>
> [...]
>
> With integration and end-to-end tests you would be able to find all the broken features.
>   [image: systems tests]
>
> Yet, this is not of any help in guessing where the bug is. The same system, with the same bug, would result in these unit test failures:

[image: unit tests]

> 

So, even though a unit test doesn't add any *business* value, it does add value in the form of reducing the amount of time spent manually testing, debugging, and sifting through code looking for the *root cause* of an issue.

Comment: thanks for the interesting link - however, if a unit test's prime (only?) value is in finding the bug quickly, then is that value not reduced if your IDE's debugging tools help you find the location of the bug quickly? It is rare I have a bug that takes more than a few hours to solve. So given the time and effort writing/maintaining unit tests, for which a mocking framework is normally needed, I'm not convinced of the benefits.

Comment: Unit tests allow you to make a change to the code and verify that all the rest of the code still works without needing to debug the entire system by hand.

Comment: @NWard thanks - I agree a unit test may tell me more quickly where the failure is, but Visual Studio's debugging normally helps me identify this quickly 'enough' for an integration test; the question is do I want to write/maintain/mock unit tests for this added speed? The answer seems to me to be no at the moment

Comment: @sturdytree "You can lead a horse to water..." :-) But in all seriousness, this isn't something that internet strangers are going to be able to convince you about; a lot of people have to see it for themselves before they're convinced - and some still remain unconvinced. Personally, the fact that I haven't had to fire up the debugger in months, despite a recent development crunch, is reason enough for me to continue using unit tests. In any case, I strongly suggest giving it a try for a while before writing it off.

Comment: @Lilshieste I should have added that I do understand the point you are making viz the value of unit tests in locating errors quickly, but of course that does not come for free - these tests have to be written and maintained and so we need to balance that cost against the gain for our specific project at hand. I've yet to spend too long in the debugger :) (but there's always a first time!)

Comment: @sturdytree You're absolutely right that the creation/maintenance of unit tests is not free. For me, that cost is paid upfront on account of using TDD, but it's definitely more noticeable if you retrofit your code with unit tests after the fact.

Comment: @sturdytree This talk by J.B Rainsberger may help to convince you that unit tests provide real value over integration tests. http://vimeo.com/80533536